# How can I save the text of the cells of a table in cypress?

Tags: node.js, cypress

im using Cypress and I need to obtain the text of some cells of the table and then compare that same text in another page later, to verify that the data is loading correctly. This is what im doing:

```
cy.get(':nth-child(1) > .datatable-body-row [class*=datatable-body-cell-label]').each((item, index, list) => {
            expect(list).to.have.length(9)
            Cypress.$(item[1]).text().invoke('text').as('serial_number')
            Cypress.$(item[3]).text().invoke('text').as('warranty_code')
            Cypress.$(item[4]).text().invoke('text').as('sku')
            cy.log(this.serial_number)
            cy.log(this.warranty_code)
            cy.log(this.sku)
        })
```

The error gives it to me in the first `'..invoke('text')..'`: `Cypress.$(...).text(...).invoke is not a function`